# How to replace keys in a dictionary with keys from another dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have two dictionaries. I want to replace the keys of one with the keys of another if the value of the second is equal to the key of the first. For example, dictionary one looks something like:

```py
dict1 = {'Adenoviridae': 'QKZ-84964', 'Alphacoronavirus': 'VWM-74278', 'Alphapapillomavirus': 'FNL-93857'}
```

and dictionary two looks something like

```py
dict2 = {'QKZ-84964': 682, 'FNL-93857': 377, 'VWM-74278': 394}
```

I want to make a new dictionary that replaces the keys of dict2 (the IDs) with the names that correspond to the ID from the first dictionary. So in this example it would look like:

```py
dict3 = {'Adenoviridae': 682, 'Alphapapillomavirus': 377, 'NMA-58554': 503, 'Alphacoronavirus': 394}
```

What is the most succinct way to go about this?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: From where does 503 come?

Comment: Welcome to SO. This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.  Invest some time with [the Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) practicing the examples. It will give you an idea of the tools Python offers to help you solve your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This takes into account the possibility that not all keys in `dict2` exist as values in `dict1`:

```
dict1 = {
    'Adenoviridae': 'QKZ-84964',
    'Alphacoronavirus': 'VWM-74278',
    'Alphapapillomavirus': 'FNL-93857'
}
dict2 = {
    'QKZ-84964': 682,
    'FNL-93857': 377,
    'VWM-74278': 394,
    'NMA-58554': 503
}

dict1_reverse = {v: k for k, v in dict1.items()}
dict3 = {(dict1_reverse[k] if k in dict1_reverse.keys() else k): v
         for k, v in dict2.items()}
```

Printing `dict3` yields the following output:

```
{
    'Adenoviridae': 682,
    'Alphapapillomavirus': 377,
    'Alphacoronavirus': 394,
    'NMA-58554': 503
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dict3 = dict()
for key, values in dict1.items():
    dict3[key] = dict2[values]
```

output

```
dict3

{'Adenoviridae': 682, 'Alphacoronavirus': 394, 'Alphapapillomavirus': 377}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```py
>>> dict3={k: dict2[v] for k, v in dict1.items()}
>>> dict3
{'Adenoviridae': 682, 'Alphacoronavirus': 394, 'Alphapapillomavirus': 377}
```

Answer (score 0):

The below code will preserve len(dict2) (I didn't know if it was required).

```
dict1 = {'Adenoviridae': 'QKZ-84964', 'Alphacoronavirus': 'VWM-74278', 'Alphapapillomavirus': 'FNL-93857'}
dict2 = {'QKZ-84964': 682, 'FNL-93857': 377, 'VWM-74278': 394}
dict3 = {}
for key, values in dict2.items():
    if key in dict1.values():
        for k1, v1 in dict1.items():
            if v1 == key:
                key = k1
    dict3[key] = values
print(dict3)

Output: {'Adenoviridae': 682, 'Alphapapillomavirus': 377, 'Alphacoronavirus': 394}
```

If there are multiple keys with the same value (which is allowed for dict objects) your result might be unexpected.